# The following bindings are missing the required DIRECTION PROPERTY and may have been placed incorrectly

Tags: azure-functions

This function monitors a storage container. If a picture is uploaded, it resizes the picture then upload the resized-picture to another container. It working just fine when run from Visual Studio Code.

```
public class ResizePictureFx
{
    [FunctionName("ResizePictureFx")]
    public void Run([BlobTrigger("product-images-original/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream inBlob, 
        string name, 
        [Blob("product-images-resized/{name}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream outBlob,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {inBlob.Length} Bytes");
        try
        {
            using (var image = Image.Load(inBlob))
            {
                image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(new ResizeOptions{
                    Size = new Size{
                        Height = 80,
                        Width = 80                    
                    },
                    Mode = ResizeMode.BoxPad
                }));

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.SaveAsPng(outBlob);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            
            log.LogInformation(e.Message, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I upload the function to Azure, I keep getting this error: the outBlog is missing a direction.

[image]

1. The message is clearly asking me to add the **direction** property in the bindings.
2. Meanwhile, I get another message telling me that I can't edit the code because it's read only.
3. There's no **Function.json** locally. All I have is **local.settings.json**

I can't find anything that explain how to deal with that directly.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Have you tried using `ICollector<T>`  interface?

Comment: Try to add this and check [Blob("product-images-resized/{name}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage", Direction = FileAccess.Write)]

Comment: @RithwikBojja `Direction could not be found, are you missing directives?`

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

I have executed locally and got results as below:

[image]

And after deploying got same error as you:

[image]

Now went to Configuration Section and changed below setting:

**`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 0`**

[image]

Then saved:

[image]

And

[image]

And now again redeployed and, now you can edit the **function.json** like below.

Then changed **function.json** as below(added direction in and out):

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-4.1.1",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "In",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{name}",
      "source": "logsAndContainerScan",
      "name": "myBlob"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "Out",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "blobPath": "resize/{name}",
      "access": 2,
      "name": "outBlob"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/FunctionApp39.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionApp39.Function1.Run"
}
```

Then checked Integration Section and error has gone:

[image]

And also you need to change the **AzureWebJobsStorage** in Configuration to the storage accounts connection string you are using local.

Try to follow above steps to get the desired result.